# sed command to change names for few files in different directories at once

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I have few folders as S1S, S2S ,S3S ... , In each of these folders there is a file1 .
This file1 in each folder consistent of

> 1990.A.BHT_S1S.dat 
> 1994.I.BHT_S1S.dat 
> 1995.K.BHT_S1S.dat 
> likewise S1S extension change according to the folder.

I'm trying to change these names into **1990.A.BHT** type for all folders using this command

```
for dir in S*
do
cd $dir
sed -i 's/_${dir}\.dat//g' file1 > file2
cd ../
done
```

but i get an empty file for file2

Can someone help me to figure out my mistake please?

Comment: You modified your `file1` files because of `-i`.

Comment: hello @konsolebox sorry what do you mean ? I've tried                              `sed  's/_${dir}\.dat//' file1 > file2 ` as well

Comment: The `-i` option allows in-place modification of the target file and send no output to stdout. This is why you got empty `file2` files, and your `file1` files have already been modified (probably).  To elaborate further, the strings `1990.A.BHT_S1S.dat`, `1994.I.BHT_S1S.dat`, and `1995.K.BHT_S1S.dat` (most likely) were already altered in `file1`.  I'm not sure how you would go reverting those changes or if you want to keep them.  Maybe you have a backup I don't know.  It's up to you.  I just informed you about the effects of `-i`.

Comment: thank you @konsolebox I understant. My file1 was not modified after using -i. But i have a backup in case .

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
parallel sed 's/_{}\.dat//' {}/file1 \> {}/file2 ::: S*S
```

Create a new file `file2` in each directory `S1S S2S S3S ...` from `file1` with the string `_SnS.dat` removed (where SnS represents the current directory).

Comment: I got this error     **parallel: command not found**

Comment: @Monika you will need to install it.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here. First, as konsolebox said in a comment, `sed -i` modifies the original file rather than producing output that can be redirected with `>`, so you need to remove that option.

Second, variables don't expand in single-quoted strings, so `'s/_${dir}\.dat//g'` doesn't use the `dir` variable, it just treats that whole thing as a literal string.

The third is probably ok, but using `cd` in a script is dangerous, because if it fails for some reason the rest of the script will run in unexpected places, with [possibly very bad results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378942/cant-initialize-osx-interrogation-folder). It's generally better to use explicit paths, like `sed ... "$dir/file1"` instead of `cd`ing to `$dir` and then using `sed ... file1`.

Finally (again probably ok here) is that you should almost always put double-quotes around variable references, to avoid weird parsing of some characters.

So here's how I'd rewrite the script snippet:

```
for dir in S*
do
    sed "s/_${dir}\.dat//g" "$dir/file1" > "$dir/file2"
done
```

p.s. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes in shell scripts; it spots three of the four problems I saw (all but the `sed -i` problem). I recommend running your scripts through it as a check.